# not recognized Python's libraries

Tags: python

it's getting a mind blowing to me: differently from the beginning I start learning/install python's its went smoothly with installation and use. From a couple of months instead when I'm installing a brand new python installation also on a brand new windows 10 installation, and then add the basic libraries with pip, I'm not able to let the libraries to work at all. I mean, the oem libraries works, but not the newest. I don't know what else I can do to set up the system to works !! Have you any recommendations ??

Here is a screen of installation entity from cmd:

```
pip install tensorflow --upgrade
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (2.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-intel==2.13.0 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (2.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=1.0.0 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: astunparse>=1.6.0 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (1.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: flatbuffers>=23.1.21 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (23.5.26)
Requirement already satisfied: gast<=0.4.0,>=0.2.1 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (0.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-pasta>=0.1.1 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py>=2.9.0 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (3.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: libclang>=13.0.0 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (16.0.6)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<=1.24.3,>=1.22 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (1.24.3)
Requirement already satisfied: opt-einsum>=2.3.2 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (3.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (23.1)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,>=3.20.3 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (4.23.4)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (65.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.12.0 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor>=1.1.0 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (2.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions<4.6.0,>=3.6.6 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (4.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt>=1.11.0 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio<2.0,>=1.24.3 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (1.56.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard<2.14,>=2.13 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (2.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-estimator<2.14,>=2.13.0 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (2.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: keras<2.14,>=2.13.1 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (2.13.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem>=0.23.1 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (0.31.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel<1.0,>=0.23.0 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from astunparse>=1.6.0->tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (0.40.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth<3,>=1.6.3 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.14,>=2.13->tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth-oauthlib<1.1,>=0.5 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.14,>=2.13->tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.14,>=2.13->tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (3.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3,>=2.21.0 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.14,>=2.13->tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (2.31.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard-data-server<0.8.0,>=0.7.0 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.14,>=2.13->tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=1.0.1 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.14,>=2.13->tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (2.3.6)
Requirement already satisfied: cachetools<6.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<3,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.14,>=2.13->tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (5.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<3,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.14,>=2.13->tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (0.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: rsa<5,>=3.1.4 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<3,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.14,>=2.13->tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (4.9)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<2.0 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<3,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.14,>=2.13->tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (1.26.16)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from google-auth-oauthlib<1.1,>=0.5->tensorboard<2.14,>=2.13->tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.14,>=2.13->tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.14,>=2.13->tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.14,>=2.13->tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (2023.5.7)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.1.1 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from werkzeug>=1.0.1->tensorboard<2.14,>=2.13->tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (2.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1<0.6.0,>=0.4.6 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1->google-auth<3,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.14,>=2.13->tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (0.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: oauthlib>=3.0.0 in c:\program files\linguaggi\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib<1.1,>=0.5->tensorboard<2.14,>=2.13->tensorflow-intel==2.13.0->tensorflow) (3.2.2)
```

In fact when debug my code(

```
import pandas as pd
import polars as pl
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import os, glob,sys
print(os.getenv("PYTHONPATH"))
# sys.path.append("C:\\Users\\Simon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Linguaggi\\Python\\Python37\\Lib\\site-packages")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# import plotly.express as px # to plot the time series plot
from sklearn import metrics # for the evaluation
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,MinMaxScaler,StandardScaler
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential,load_model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten,TimeDistributed,RepeatVector,Dense,Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D,LSTM,ConvLSTM2D,MaxPool1D,MaxPooling1D

from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import pacf,acf
```

) both with latest spyder ide version and from console, I obtain such error:

```
C:\Program Files\Linguaggi\Python\Python311;C:\Program Files\Linguaggi\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages;C:\Program Files\Linguaggi\Python\Python311\Lib
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File C:\Program Files\Linguaggi\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File d:\documenti\develope\python\forecaster\multyvariate_150-convlstm2d-k(1.2)-elu-h150-adam-mse_horizon_19_ok.py:17
    from sklearn import metrics # for the evaluation

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

..and this will hepen for almost the not standard libraries like: tensofrflow, sklearn, polars, statsmodels and so on..

Comment: The most likable is that you are installing the libraries in one python instance and running a different one

Comment: I don't see `sklearn` in the list of installed libraries at the top of your post.  Did you install it?

Comment: To help us help you, you should tell us more about your configuration -  how you installed python (e.g anaconda, or base Python for windows), if you are using any virtual environments, etc. Most likely problem is you have more than one Python interpreter setup. Check that your libraries are there via pip list, etc.

Comment: @ John - yes I do indeed, like several other not listed in the screen shot..

Comment: @solocazzimiei As a sidenote, did you install [`sklearn`](https://pypi.org/project/sklearn/) or `scikit-learn`?

Comment: @painsaco - you right ! the installation of windows is a brand new win10 ver 22H2. Python was installed via python 3.1.1. installer as usual. ..and libraries via pip : were downloaded and installed the lastest version available without use of any venv

Answer (score 0):

Yes, installing multiple libraries that is needed for doing projects that involves data science can be really tricky, because when you install them using `pip`, most of them have many dependencies, sub-modules that needs to be installed, and some configurations exclusive to each module.

But, I noticed that all modules you mentioned are presented in `anaconda`. My suggestion is, instead of trying to install each module individually, download and install `anaconda`.

It's a gret tool for data scientists and for those that want to work with things like Tensorflow and Numpy. The installation comes with a bunch of customized options, including pre-configured modules that are all made to work with eachother.

Anaconda comes with TensorFlow, Pandas, Matplotlib, Numpy, Sklearn, etc. It will be much easier and faster for you if you choose to install it this way.

You can find it [here](https://www.anaconda.com/download).

**Edit**: A alternative to Anaconda.

So, since you commented that you don't want to give Anaconda a chance, my recommendation for you is: Start using Virtual Enviroments.

PyCharm IDE has really easy built-in configurations that you can, just with a single click, create a project that already comes bundled with all packages you need for a Data Science project.

This is it's [official documentation explaining how to do it](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html).

This way you can have independent enviroments that won't conflict with eachother, so, if you start seeing errors, just start another one.

Apart from that... There is'nt much you can do. As I said, installing multiple libraries that are as large as TensorFlow, Pandas, etc, can be really tricky. It's faster and more practical if you just use one of the two methods I said here.

Comment: Thanks. Anaconda seams too heavy to manage.. to me

Comment: Well ... it seems like you are struggling to do it by hand in a "light-weight" way.  So why don't you give the Anaconda suggestion a try anyway?   The alternative is 1) read the documentation for the packages you are trying to use to work out the dependencies, 2) work out which packages / versions you need, 3) install them by hand, and 4) repeat the process each time you need to bump versions.

Comment: (And if you are going to do this by hand, at least use a virtual environment ... and document your app's dependencies via a `requirements.txt` file or something.)

Comment: @solocazzimiei It does look like a huge monster initially but it's actually easier to use than doing it all by hand. But, I edited the question with another suggestion to you, on a easier and more friendly alternative for installing multiple packages.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have multiple versions of python installed; And you are installing modules for a wrong version. this problem can be solved by using the following command :

`python-<version> -m pip install <module-name>`

where *version* is your python version formatted like this: #.#

You might also find this question useful -> [Dealing with multiple Python versions and PIP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4910393/20565017)

Comment: Thanks, this is not the case I guess: as per a fresh OS installation, after python v3.1.1 install, PIP governate the rest of installed libs. I didn't hacked nor double python versions..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is not resolutive from the original trouble, but using [WinPython](https://winpython.github.io/#overview) all libs are visible and works smoothly.